# Application of the uniform boundedness Principle.

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, solution-verification

Here is the question:

Let $A = [a_{ij}]_{i,j = 1}^{\infty}$ be an infinite matrix of real numbers and suppose that, for any $x \in \ell^2,$ the sequence $Ax$ belongs to $\ell^2.$ Prove that the operator $T,$ defined by $T(x) = Ax,$ is a bounded operator on $\ell^2.$

**Here is my trial: **

We will use the uniform bounded theorem Principle, since we showed that  $(\ell^2,\| x\|_{2})$ is a normed space. and it is easy to show that its complete by showing that every Cauchy sequence converges using $\| .\|_{2}$, then $(\ell^2 , \| x\|_{2})$ is a Banach space and since by the given we have that for any $x \in \ell^2,$ the sequence $Ax$ belongs to $\ell^2.$ Which can be formulated mathematically as follows:

According to the givens we can define $A : \ell^2 \rightarrow \ell^2  $ by $$A x = A (\xi_{1}, \xi_{2}, ...) = (\beta_{1}, \beta_{2}, ...), $$
Where

$$
[a_{ij}]\begin{bmatrix}
\xi_{1}  \\
\xi_{2} \\
\vdots 
\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}
\beta_{1}  \\
\beta_{2} \\
\vdots 
\end{bmatrix}
$$

i.e., $\beta_{i} = \sum_{j=1}^{\infty} a_{ij} \xi_{j}$ and $ \|Ax\|^{2} = \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} |\beta_{i}|^2 < \infty $. Hence $\sup \{\|A x \|\} < \infty $  and hence  $\sup \{\|T \|\} = \sup \{\|A \|\} < \infty  $ as required.

Is my solution correct?

Comment: it is not right, note that $\sup_{x\in \ell^2}\|Ax\|=\infty$, by example take the sequence defined by $x_n:=n y$ for some non-zero $y\in \ell^2$

Comment: in my previous comment there is a mistake, beacuse $y\neq 0$ doesnt ensure that $Ay\neq 0$, there is a correct reasoning: if $A\neq 0$ then there exists some $y\in\ell^2$ such that $\|Ay\|>0$, therefore $\|Ax_n\|=n\|Ay\|$ and so $\sup_{x\in \ell^2}\|Ax\|=\infty$

Comment: Uniform Boundedness Principle deals with flamiy of operators and it says nothing when there is single operator. I don't even see  a sequence / family of operators in your argument.

Comment: @Masacroso so how can I solve this problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Define $T_Nx= (\sum\limits_{k=1}^{N} a_{ij}x_j)$. Verify that $T_N$ is a bounded opeartor and $(\|T_N(x)\|)$ is a bounded sequence for each fixed $x$. Apply UBP to finish the proof.

Comment: What is the idea of your hint here? are you truncating the $x,$ ? and if so why?

Comment: UBP tells you that point-wise limit of bounded operators between Banach spaces is bounded. Our map $T$ is defined by an infinite sum which suggests that we write it a the limit of partial sums. The partial sums give us bounded operators and $T$ is their limit.  @Happy

Comment: So we are not using the UBP itself but the following consequence of it: **Theorem:**

Let $X,Y$ be Banach spaces and let $\{T_{n}\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ and $T$ be operators in $\mathcal{L}(X,Y).$ then $\lim_{n} T_{n}x = Tx,$ for all $x \in X,$ iff 

(a)the sequence $\{T_{n}\}$ is bounded;

(b)$\lim_{n} T_{n}x$ exists on a dense subset of $X.$                                                                                                          .... am I correct?

Comment: Also, why we decided to use the UBP? what is special about this problem that leads us to think of UBP?

Comment: No. you are assuming that $T$ is bounded so your rersult is not useful. We are using the fact that if $T_n$'s are bounded and $Tx=lim T_n(x)$ exists for all $x$ then $T$ is  (linear and) bounded.

Comment: I do not see anything about the point-wise limit in the statement of the UBP I am using. Are you speaking about the Banach-Steinhaus Theorem ?

Comment: UBP (Uniform Boundednes Principle) is just another name for Banach Steinhaus Theorem! @Happy

Comment: I know that verifying that $T_{N}$ is a bounded operator is by Cauchy-Schwartz .... How about verifying that $(\|T_N(x)\|)$ is a bounded sequence for every $x$, how can I do that?

Comment: Is this proposition useful in this proof ?proposition: "The series $\sum_{n =1}^{\infty} a_{n} b_{n}$ converges absolutely for every convergent sequence $\{b_{n}\}$ iff $\sum_{n =1}^{\infty} |a_{n}|$ converges." will it be helpful here in our case? the problem is that here in our case we are in $l^2.$

Comment: On pg. 269 in Royden real analysis fourth edition they are different things not the same.

Comment: UBP is not Banach-Saks-Steinhaus Theorem on pg. 269

Comment: I have proved that $T_{N}$ is bounded with $$\|T_N \| \leq (\sum_{j=1}^{N}|a_{ij}|^2 )^{1/2}$$ Am I correct?

Comment: Now I am stuck in proving that $(\|T_{N}x\|)_{N \in \mathbb{N}}$ is a bounded sequence for each fixed $x$ I need a condition on $x$ like it has finitely many nonzero terms or any other thing or here is what the given that for each x the sequence $Ax \in l^2$ comes into play?